# react, setState does not work in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number : 0
        };

        this.handleIncrease = this.handleIncrease.bind(this);
        this.handleDecrease = this.handleDecrease.bind(this);
    }

    handleIncrease = () => {
        this.setState=({
            number: this.state.number + 1
        });
        console.log("handleIncrease()");
    }
    handleDecrease = () => {
        this.setState({
            number: this.state.number - 1
        });
        console.log("handleDecrease()");
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <hr/>
                <h1>Counter</h1>
                <p>number : {this.state.number}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrease}>+</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>-</button>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

It works when I press the - button, but it does not work when I press the + button and I get an error:

> TypeError: _this.setState is not a function
>   Counter._this.handleDecrease

Comment: `this.setState=(`, remove `=` before `(` in `handleIncrease` function.

Comment: thank you!!!!! so much!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!! wow!!!!!!!!! i m stupid!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the equal sign:

```
handleIncrease = () => {
    >>>> this.setState({
       number: this.state.number + 1
     });
     console.log("handleIncrease()");
    }
```

Also, pass a function in setState when using the previous state to set new state as state updates can be asynchronous.

More Info: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number : 0
        };

        this.handleIncrease = this.handleIncrease.bind(this);
        this.handleDecrease = this.handleDecrease.bind(this);
    }

    handleIncrease = () => {
       //here remove equal
        this.setState({
            number: this.state.number + 1
        });
        console.log("handleIncrease()");
    }
    handleDecrease = () => {
        this.setState({
            number: this.state.number - 1
        });
        console.log("handleDecrease()");
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <hr/>
                <h1>Counter</h1>
                <p>number : {this.state.number}</p>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrease}>+</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrease}>-</button>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```